# Edit Pdf using FPDF/FPDI in php

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

Are we able to change amount in already generated PDF file ? I want to change Total amount only in bellow screenshot, I don't want to regenerate that PDF file ?

Any suggestion welcome.

[image]

Comment: you could convert it to docx, change the content and convert it back to pdf. For example by using online services like cloudconvert or others ? ..

Comment: I usually use inkscape to edit PDFs. It's free and open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. With FPDI you can "only" import existing pages into a reusable structure. You cannot edit the page content.

Comment: Thanks you very much.